# Prove that if $n + 1 | n! + 1$ then $n+1$ is a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How can we prove that if : $n+1|n!+1$ then $n$ is a prime number.
My try:
I try to do contrapositive: If $n$ is composite then $n+1 \nmid n!+1$ and then to get that if $n$ is composite so $n+1=ab$ when $2 \le a \le n $ so that $a|n+1$ but here I don't have idea how to continue, is this the good way?

Comment: I want to understand something: if $n+1|n!+1$ so that $n+1 \equiv n!+1 (mod p)$ ?

Comment: @Xavi: No, $n+1\mid n!+1$ is the same as $n!+1\equiv 0\pmod{n+1}$, or equivalently $n!\equiv -1\pmod{n+1}$.

Comment: @Troposphere And then how you can know that $n$ is a prime number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n+1=ab$ then what you now want to *disprove* is that $ab \mid n!+1$.

However, $a$ is among the factors of $n!$. How could $n!+1$ then be a multiple of $ab$?

---

This is one of the directions of [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), which is usually phrased:

> $n\in\mathbb N$ is a prime number if and only if $(n-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod n$.

(Note that the $n$ in statement is what your statement calls $n+1$).

Comment: Yes, Wilson's Theorem does have 2 directions. The easier direction is the exercise given here. While the other direction, showing that $n+1$ a prime implies $n+1$ *does* divide $n!+1$ is much harder.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).